# Delete optional property after type predicate check while maintaining static analysis

Tags: typescript, narrowing

I have an interface `I` with only optional properties. In my case `I` is a generic. I need a type narrowing function that still allows to `delete` the narrowed property. The following code shows the problem.

```
interface I {
    value?: number
}

function check(i: I): i is I & { value: number } {
    return "value" in i
}

function test(i: I) {
    if (check(i)) {
        i.value += 1 // ok
        delete i.value // error: The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.
    }
}

// i as I is not an option to force deletion because it allows the access
// to i.value after deletion
function test2(i: I) {
    if (check(i)) {
        i.value += 1 // ok
        delete (i as I).value // ok
        i.value += 1 // !!! still ok
    }
}

// expected behaviour should be something like
function test(v: I) {
  if ("value" in v) {
    v.value += 5 // ok
    delete v.value // ok
    v.value += 5 // error: understandable and good
  }
}
```

The problem is, that the narrowing creates a new interface with `value` as a required type. So I need syntax to say that `value` can be optional / removed but currently contains a value.

A workaround would be to define a function for deleting that renarrows the value back to optional.

Is there some syntax or pattern to allow the use of the `delete` keyword?

Comment: try `i is I & { value: number }` this makes `value` property required and `delete` wants it to be optional. you can do this : `delete (i as I).value`

Comment: @Eldar I have `i is I & { value: number }` in the example. The question would be more if it is possible to use `delete` without using `as`

Comment: I very much doubt what you're asking for is possible; there is no *type* in TypeScript that says "this property is known to be present but is optional (so you can delete it)".  That state can occur due to control flow analysis (e.g., `if (typeof i.value !== "undefined")`), but there's no way to turn that into a type `X` so that you can have a custom type guard function return `i is X`.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. You did understand my question correctly. If this is not possible I will mark your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't express what you're doing with a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) whose return type is of the form `i is X` for some type `X`.  TypeScript doesn't have a type that means "the `value` property of type `number` is optional (so it may be `delete`d), but known to be present (so it can assigned to `number`)".  The type `{value?: number}` means the property is optional but possibly missing, and the type `{value: number}` means the property is known to be present but is required.  Neither is appropriate for the return type of a custom type guard function.

The desired state is possible to achieve via [control flow anlysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) as you've seen (although I'd change your example to

```
function test(i: I) {
    if (typeof i.value !== "undefined") {
        i.value += 5 // ok
        delete i.value // ok
        i.value += 5 // error: understandable and good
    }
}
```

instead of `if ("value" in i)`).  But again, there's no appropriate way to represent that post-checked state as giving `i` a new *type*.

---

I didn't find a relevant [TypeScript GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues); so you *might* want to file a new feature request for a type that works this way.  But I doubt it would be implemented, since it's not a very common situation, and the workaround is to use the direct type guard instead of a custom type guard function.  If you do decide to file a feature request, you should take care to demonstrate why available workarounds don't suffice.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4Chm+QNzgBsBXCAfgC5kQSBbAI2iwF8ssYSQExgB7EMgQALCAgDWACmDVUASmrBkwAM5pkAMkwFiZarUbRkLTDjxQIYElEEAiQqQi3lg4K3aduvAckgqwAIzSsnKmeMowyJIiYlLAcqHY4eHAAHQOZMgA1AC8yAHIAPSFyHziZsnIACYQRJYoaRkoxcjQUHxQ1AAqoqUADtBwIFWlkXDIAOQ1dZAT-YNgHch0JP7ITP3eIMSpFcbuWC1KcGroqjR8YMhDm-yCi8gwHUjVtZZ362Jwqw1XxER8ADuajAvUQSBUKkOJQejV0KDgMEgUFeMzuHC4PA+fjAACZgmhEntgJFoqIJNIEmFKsp0vDsnkCi0yntwtN6lFjqc5HTHEUSiyabSmgz8vzkABCKXIfzAIhEUrlcJsNgYrzYiD+ADMBPk1NwJKiYAAngM+JE4XyJTk8rYuDUYKAIFVbEShZbMrlkABWcWCmnsyDC+nMpU0j0oL2+lptDrUe3QfxDKpwBh1a7DZAAcz4fCqexVQA)